# How to Begin with a Custom Error log function in python

Tags: python, logging, tornado-motor

I want to write a custom error log class, which would show me the errors returned by the code. 
I don't use google app engine, I use python tornado framework.

So can anyone guide me with steps to follow.

I have actually got the steps to follow to create the custom logger from the below link:

[Python: custom logging across all modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870380/python-custom-logging-across-all-modules)

But how do i actually store the logs in db and pull it and post it on my front end.

Comment: do you mean logging module or are you looking for equivalent of php's error function?

Comment: A custom logging module, where in i can push it to db and retrieve in to the front end form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(...)
try:
    do.something()
except Exception:
    logging.exception("aiii!")
```

Eventually you'll want to move off `basicConfig`.