# Python Custom Logger

Tags: python, logging, tornado-motor

I have actually got the steps to follow to create the custom logger from the below link:

[Python: custom logging across all modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870380/python-custom-logging-across-all-modules)

But how do i actually store the logs in Mongodb and pull it and post it on my front end.

Comment: You'll just need to implement your own logging Handler and then add it to some loggers in the logging configuration.

Comment: I have implemented a logging handler. But could not figure out to push it into mongodb

Comment: You don't have to "push handler to mongodb" your handler needs to establis connection to this database and then post logs to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Create a file-like Class,that is  implement its write method in which you can write logics for inserting data to mongo
2. Create a StreamHandler using your own file-like Object as a stream.
3. logger.addHandler(yourHandler)